# Examples of when to use the manifest meta-data tag

Tags: android, android-manifest

What should the `meta-data` tag in the Android Manifest be used for? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Is the meta-data field publicly accessible (i.e. can app A view the manifest meta-data of app B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should the meta-data tag in the Android Manifest be used for?

Sometimes, that is for when a library needs some configuration data, as an alternative to your having to provide that data in Java. For example, `FileProvider` (from the Android Support libraries) uses this to configure what files it can serve.

Sometimes, this will be used by bits of the Android framework, such as app widgets and device administrators.

> Is the meta-data field publicly accessible

Yes, this data is public, through `PackageManager`.